# Sitecore Release Contact Processor

Tags: mongodb, experience-profile

We are facing an issue on our Production environment: the Experience Profile Dashboard is empty. When we look at the logs we found `Tracker.IsActive= false` and it says that `Release contact Processor` is skipped.

Can this be the reason that Sitecore Experience Profile DashBoard is empty?

What actually does `ReleaseContactProcessor` do in the `End Analytics Pipeline`? Is this the processor which pushes data to the Reporting Db from MongoDB?

Comment: Can you update the question with your exact log entry? There are a number of reasons why the `ReleaseContact` processor might get skipped.

Comment: I see this error mostly                                                                                                Cannot submit pending item: MongoDB.Driver.MongoQueryException: QueryFailure flag was Executor error: Overflow sort stage buffered data usage of 34089254 bytes exceeds internal limit of 33554432 bytes (response was { "$err" : "Executor error: Overflow sort stage buffered data usage of 34089254 bytes exceeds internal limit of 33554432 bytes", "code" : 17144 }).

Answer (score 1):

There are a few reasons why the `ReleaseContact` processor might be skipped.

Here is the code for that method:

```
public void Process(PipelineArgs args)
{
  if (Tracker.Current == null)
  {
    Log.Debug("Tracker is not initialized. ReleaseContact processor is skipped");
  }
  else
  {
    Session session = Tracker.Current.Session;
    Assert.IsNotNull((object) session, "Tracker.Current.Session");
    if (session.TransferInProcess)
      Log.Debug("Contact is being transferred. ReleaseContact processor is skipped");
    else if (session.Contact == null)
      Log.Debug("Contact is null. ReleaseContact processor is skipped");
    else if (session.Settings.IsTransient)
    {
      Log.Debug("Session is in TRANSIENT MODE. ReleaseContact processor is skipped");
    }
    else
    {
      if (session.IsReadOnly)
        return;
      ContactManager contactManager = Factory.CreateObject("tracking/contactManager", true) as ContactManager;
      string message = "tracking/contactManager";
      Assert.IsNotNull((object) contactManager, message);
      Contact contact = session.Contact;
      contactManager.SaveAndReleaseInSharedSessionState(contact);
      session.Contact = (Contact) null;
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, if the Tracker is not enabled, a transfer is already in process, the `session.Contact` is null or `session.Settings.IsTransient` is true. In any of those situations the processor is skipped. Your log files should tell you which.

Based on your statement that `Tracker.IsActive == false` my guess is your logs look like this:

```
5000 15:54:43 DEBUG [Analytics]: Tracker.IsActive == false. EndAnalytics pipeline is terminated

5000 15:54:43 DEBUG Tracker is not initialized. ReleaseContact processor is skipped
```

In that case check the following settings in your config. They need to both be set to true:

```
<setting name="Xdb.Enabled" value="true" />
<setting name="Xdb.Tracking.Enabled" value="true" />
```

Also, make sure that the `enableAnalytics` attribute on your site definition is not `false`.

Another thing to check is that you have `@Html.Sitecore().VisitorIdentification()` in your main layout file.

Hopefully this should get you close.

Comment: Could you please help me with patch.config as well i am not able to hit the processor

Comment: I want to know which processor is responsible to flush the all the contacts in MongoDB to ReportingDB as my experience profile dashboard is still empty

Comment: If I'm reading it right, that is the processor. Your Tracker is not active, that is why you don't have any data in your experience profile. Might be best to take this to Slack or the Community forums so people can discuss and help resolve the issue.

Comment: I need an invite to Slack Could you please help with it

Comment: Go here: https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2018/02/26/sitecore-slack-community-guidelines/

Comment: After i deployed the pipeline i got two kind of logs                                                1) Tracker is not initialized. ReleaseContact processor is skipped 2)  session.IsReadOnly any clues here